# Julia Error Building Mongo.jl Package on Windows 10

Tags: windows, mongodb, julia

I installed Julia v0.6.2 on Windows 10.
Every other package was installed without a problem, but Mongo.jl give me this error while building it.

```
Pkg.build("Mongo")

INFO: Building LibBSON
===============================[ ERROR: LibBSON ]===============================

LoadError: None of the selected providers can install dependency libbson.
Use BinDeps.debug(package_name) to see available providers

while loading C:\Users\"user"\.julia\v0.6\LibBSON\deps\build.jl, in expression starting on line 27

================================================================================
INFO: Building Mongo
================================[ ERROR: Mongo ]================================

LoadError: None of the selected providers can install dependency libmongoc.
Use BinDeps.debug(package_name) to see available providers

while loading C:\Users\"user"\.julia\v0.6\Mongo\deps\build.jl, in expression starting on line 26

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: LibBSON and Mongo had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in C:\Users\ciko9\.julia\v0.6
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with Pkg.build("LibBSON", "Mongo")
 - build a single package by running its deps/build.jl script

================================================================================
```

I already opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/Lytol/Mongo.jl/issues/37), but I'd like to fix it asap. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try do what it says? "Use `BinDeps.debug(package_name)` to see available providers" then try and install the relevant dependencies yourself: libmongoc & libbson?

Comment: Yes, this is the result:
`INFO: Reading build script...
The package declares 1 dependencies.
 - Library "libmongoc"
    - Providers:
      - Autotools Build (can't provide)`
What do you suggest me?

Comment: Have a go at installing the mongo c drivers yourself. [Installing the MongoDB C Driver](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#building-on-windows). Sorry I can't give any windows specific advice as I haven't used in ages! After you've installed try `Pkg.build("LibBSON", "Mongo")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is first to install manually the mongo c drivers. 
Second, to copy the mongo-c-drivers folder to the mongo e libbson folder inside julia, then make a new file deps.jl for each package and write this:

```
    # Macro to load a library
     macro checked_lib(libname, path)
     ((VERSION >= v"0.4.0-dev+3844" ? Base.Libdl.dlopen_e : Base.dlopen_e)(path) == C_NULL) && error("Unable to load \n\n$libname ($path)\n\nPlease re-run Pkg.build(package), and restart Julia.")
     quote const $(esc(libname)) = $path end
     end
     # Load dependencies
     @checked_lib libbson "C:\\Users\\"userName"\\.julia\\v0.6\\LibBSON\\mongo-c-driver\\bin\\libbson-1.0.dll"
    # Load-hooks
```